# Replace without the replace function

Tags: python

> Assignment: Let X and Y be two words. Find/Replace is a common word processing operation that finds each occurrence of word X and replaces it with word Y in a given document.
>
> Your task is to write a program that performs the Find/Replace operation. Your program will prompt the user for the word to be replaced (X), then the substitute word (Y ). Assume that the input document is named input.txt. You must write the result of this Find/Replace operation to a file named output.txt. Lastly, you cannot use the replace() string function built into Python (it would make the assignment much too easy).
>
> To test your code, you should modify input.txt using a text editor such as Notepad or IDLE to contain different lines of text. Again, the output of your code must look exactly like the sample output.

This is my code:

```
 input_data = open('input.txt','r') #this opens the file to read it. 
 output_data = open('output.txt','w') #this opens a file to write to. 

 userStr= (raw_input('Enter the word to be replaced:')) #this prompts the user for a word 
 userReplace =(raw_input('What should I replace all occurences of ' + userStr + ' with?')) #this      prompts the user for the replacement word


 for line in input_data:
    words = line.split()
    if userStr in words:
       output_data.write(line + userReplace)
    else:
       output_data.write(line)
        
 print 'All occurences of '+userStr+' in input.txt have been replaced by '+userReplace+' in   output.txt' #this tells the user that we have replaced the words they gave us


 input_data.close() #this closes the documents we opened before 
 output_data.close()
```

It won't replace anything in the output file. Help!

Comment: you need to find where the word occurs in the line, then change that part of the line.

Comment: you should try to solve this by yourself. It's a homework assignment. If you get your answer here, you won't learn how to do it by yourself... Come on! It's a nice homework! i wish i had this kind of homework when i was at school....

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `replace` function at all...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code just sticks the replacement string onto the end of the line if a match is found:

```
if userStr in words:
   output_data.write(line + userReplace)  # <-- Right here
else:
   output_data.write(line)
```

Since you can't use `.replace()`, you will have to work around it. I'd find where the word occurs in your line, cut that part out, and then stick `userReplace` in its place.

To do that, try something like this:

```
for line in input_data:
   while userStr in line:
      index = line.index(userStr)  # The place where `userStr` occurs in `line`.

      # You need to cut `line` into two parts: the part before `index` and
      # the part after `index`. Remember to consider in the length of `userStr`.

      line = part_before_index + userReplace + part_after_index

   output_data.write(line + '\n')  # You still need to add a newline
```

A slightly more annoying way to work around `replace` would be to use `re.sub()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `split` and `join` to implement a `replace`

```
output_data.write(userReplace.join(line.split(userStr)))
```